# Why am I getting 304 when - "every time I visit the page" is on?

Tags: internet-explorer, http-headers, browser-cache, fiddler, http-status-code-304

We have an (old) intranet site which has this setting

`Every time I visit the page` : true

[image]

But still I can see in developer tools many `304` replies :

[image]

**Question** :

- Why is that ? How can I force to see all  responses as `200` ?

Related info :

`IIS 7.5`

It happens in `IE9-10` ( the site run only on IE) ( the browser mode is changed to ie9 because it is an old web site (intranet) which wasnt adjusted  to the new browsers.

Using fiddler  - it also shows 304.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Request header example :

[image]

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this? The current behavior provides better performance and the same correctness as turning off caching entirely...

Comment: @EricLaw I didn't build the system. there are some ajax call which doesn't work if "every time I visit the page" is not set.

Comment: You misunderstand. You're getting 304s when you have `Every time I visit the page` set. That's fine. Leave the 304s alone -- they're doing what they're supposed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Checks for newer versions of stored pages every time I visit the webpage

Simply means that IE will (**'check'**, hence) include the caching-related headers (`If-Modified-Since`, `ETag` etc) in the request. The server will then return `200` only if it feels that there's a cache 'miss'.

Also, note that the settings in question ONLY apply when the server fails to specify the cache-freshness lifetime using a `Cache-Control` or `Expires` response header. See the **Conditional Requests** section of [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250442%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to learn more.

If you want to configure your server to disable client-side caching for the entire directory, try this:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="your_assets_dir">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

http 304 code is SERVER code, so your browser and its' settings not really relate to each other, 304 code means that browser sent if-modified-since, and server checked this date and returned "not modified"